# How to interrupt Queue.get() in Process()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyqt5

I cant stop a Process when a queue is implemented in the target function `run_event()`. The queue is required to return a value from the target function. The process can be stopped without a queue.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue,

def run_event(params, queue):
    """Run some task that cant be stopped by polling
       returns a dataframe
    """
    out = arbritrarySolver(params) # Runs a solver that returns a dataframe
    queue.put(out)


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super().__init__()
        self.params = params

    def stop_work(self):
        self.process.terminate()

    def start_work(self):
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.process = Process(target=run_event, args=(self.params, self.queue))
        self.process.start()
        output = self.queue.get()  # output of run_event

class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def start_event(self):
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.obj = worker.Worker(params)
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.obj.start_work)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.obj.stop_work)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def initUI(self):
        self.runButton = QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.start_event)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.runButton)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Gui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do i implement a solution that interrupts `run_event()` with the stop button when the queue is implemented?

Comment: Please let me know if the edit was insufficient! cheers.

Comment: Where do you want to get the result?

Comment: The idea is to set the result as a worker class variable so that I can perform more work on it After the solving process is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are blocking the secondary thread where the worker lives when you use self.queue.get(), instead a possible strategy is to use a timer to check the status of the queue and, accordingly, to send a signal to the GUI with the result.

```py
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from foo_package import arbritrarySolver


def run_event(params, queue):
    """Run some task that cant be stopped by polling
       returns a dataframe
    """
    out = arbritrarySolver(params)  # Runs a solver that returns a dataframe
    queue.put(out)


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    resultChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.m_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.m_timer.timeout.connect(self.check_result)
        self.process = None

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def stop_work(self):
        if isinstance(self.process, mp.Process):
            self.process.terminate()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def start_work(self, params):
        self.queue = mp.Queue()
        self.process = mp.Process(target=run_event, args=(params, self.queue))
        self.process.start()
        self.m_timer.start(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def check_result(self):
        if not self.process.is_alive():
            self.finished.emit()
            self.m_timer.stop()

        if not self.queue.empty():
            r = self.queue.get(block=False)
            self.resultChanged.emit(r)


class Gui(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.worker_thread.start()

        self.obj = Worker()
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.obj.resultChanged.connect(self.onResultChanged)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.onFinished)

        self.initUI()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_event(self):
        params = "aaa", "bbb"
        wrapper = partial(self.obj.start_work, params)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        self.runButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.stopButton.setDisabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onFinished(self):
        self.runButton.setDisabled(False)
        self.stopButton.setDisabled(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def onResultChanged(self, result):
        print(result)

    def initUI(self):
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.stopButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.runButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run")
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.start_event)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.obj.stop_work)
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.runButton)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.obj.stop_work()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Gui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The AbstractSolver is an object that should not be modified. We can only kill it by ending the process.

Comment: @zza Okay what you say and my code does not indicate otherwise, in my code I have only set an example to emulate the task for my example.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear earlier. I cant apply your solution to my situation as the code for my task __arbritrarySolver(params)__ cannot be modified. That was why i have to terminate the process to stop it.

Comment: @zza It seems that you have not understood my solution, now just modify `from foo_package import arbritrarySolver` to do your import and then it will work with your arbritrarySolver.

Comment: @elyllanesc Please ignore the above comment, i wrote it before seeing your edit. It is working as expected now! Could you briefly explain the purpose of Qtimer.singleshot() in this scenario? Also, is there a reason to favor passing the params with partial() vs passing it through instantation of the worker class. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `timeout` argument to `multiprocessing.Queue` in combination with `time.sleep` to periodically unblock execution and process events (such as exceptions):

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


def run_event(params, queue):
    time.sleep(10)
    queue.put(params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = mp.Queue()
    process = mp.Process(target=run_event, args=('foo', queue))
    process.start()

    while True:
        try:
            result = queue.get(timeout=0.1)
        except mp.queues.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            break

    print(result)
```

In your example, you could replace `while True` with something like `while not self._stop_execution` and set `self._stop_execution = True` on your button click.